# Overwriting a single local file gives OS Error

Tags: python, pdf

Iam trying to write the contents of the URLS in the list into a local file 'test.pdf' .

It seems to work well for first few records, then it shows OS Error 22.

I have 24 items in my list.

list_urls=[val1,value2,val3,val4...val 24]

After every file read, test.pdf needs to be overwritten with the next file contents.

for x in list_urls:
print (x)
filename=r'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\test.pdf'

```
with open(filename,'wb') as output_file:
    
    
    response = File.open_binary(ctx,x)
    
    output_file.write(response.content)
    
    
    output_file.seek(0)
    output_file.close()
```

Its working for the first 12 files and then shows OS ERROR 22.

What am i missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: OSError 22 means that the file path is (for some reason) invalid. Does the part of the file path that you've obscured change? Also, why seek and close when you're using a context manager ? I'm also intrigued by the apparent mixture of Unix and Windows style pathnames. What platform are you running this on?

Comment: Running it on windows platform. No its the same file path. the write works for list few files and then eventually shows this error.I re ran the same code for 2 elements in th elist and it works fine.Doe sit depend on the number of times the file is opened?

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code. As it stands (notwithstanding the unnecessary close and seek calls) I see no reason for that to happen

Comment: used output_file.flush() after every write. It works now !

Comment: Really? Any output buffer should be flushed upon close(). Did you take out the seek and close?